# Не срабатывает условие

Tags: javascript

Почему не отображается женщина на пенсии, когда `age >= 55`? С "мужским" все корректно работает.

```
var pensionAge = (floor==="мужской") && (age>=60) ? "да" : "нет";
(floor==="женский") && (age>=55) ? "да" : "нет";

alert(вы на пенсии: pensionAge)
```

Comment: в вашем коде где должно отображаться?

Comment: Потому что Вы не сохраняете результат и нигде его не выводите.

Comment: прошу прощения не стал скидывать весь код только отрывок.

Comment: `floor` ;DD ???

Comment: Пол в смысле женщина, мужчина - это `sex`, а не `floor`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin "gender"

Comment: @Igor да, или gender

Comment: Спасибо ребят что поправили. Я только начал изучать js. Подскажите пожалуйста еще как можно "gender" текстовый констан преоброзовать в логическое значение?

Answer (score 5):

```
var pensionAge = ((floor==="мужской" && age>=60) || (floor==="женский" && age>=55)) ? "да" : "нет";
alert(вы на пенсии: pensionAge)
```

---

> как можно "gender" текстовый констан преоброзовать в логическое
> значение

```
var isMale   = gender == "мужской";
var isFemale = gender == "женский";
```

Comment: ребят подскажите пожалуйста еще как можно сохранить результат confirm в логической переменой                                                                                              var gender = confirm ("ваш пол - мужской?") ? 'мужской' : 'женский';